# Why can't we see whats inside black holes?

Tags: black-holes

May be it's a dumb question. But I like to know why can't we see the matter or  objects that are inside a black hole? Because I read that black holes suck huge objects like planets, stars or bla bla bla. Ca't we see these bigger items?

Comment: They "suck in" information and convert it to "bla bla bla". Quite a mystery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to see something light must come from it and reach our eyes (or telescope). Past the event horizon of a black hole nothing can escape the gravitational pull of the black hole. This includes light. Therefore, we cannot see anything from inside the black hole because light cannot leave the black hole to get to us.

Comment: This is incorrect. Nothing can escape he black hole not because of the gravitational pull, but because time inside the black hole runs to the center while the event horizon exists only in the past. Nothing can escape the black hole, because nothing can move backward in time.

Comment: @safesphere And this effect is due to gravity. I think a classical answer to this question is sufficient given the apparent level of the person asking the question. I do not think going into general relativity would have helped. Thank you for giving more insight to those who know more advanced physics topics! :)